# Using event.target to get element

Tags: jquery

I'm basically trying to get the target element from event.target and if not equal process.
How can i get the below thing to work ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).click(function(event) {

       if(event.target!='#contents') {  //If clicked element is not div #contents show alert .. //How can i achieve this ?
         alert("..");
       }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use

```
   //If clicked element id is not contents 
   if(event.target.id !== 'contents') {  
     alert("..");
   }
```

EDIT - if the structure is that of your comment use:

```
  if($(event.target).closest('div#contents').length === 0){
    alert('there is no div with id === "contents" in the ancestors of the clicked li');
   }
```

EDIT 2 - explanation of my code. If you  have this markup

```
<div id="contents"><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul></div>
```

this code means

```
//event.target is a DOM element, so wrap it into a jQuery object
$(event.target)
        .closest('div#contents')//find a div element going up the dom tree. 
                                //This method returns a jQuery collection that it's 
                                //empty if the div is not found
        .length //the collection has a length 
                //property that is equal to the number of found elements
```

Comment: +1 @user1184100: `event.target` is an object, not a string. Its **`id`** is a string.

Comment: When i do a console.log(event.target); it returns li of div .. but not div id #contents so above code will not work :(
Structure is something like this <div id="contents"><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul></div>

Comment: @user1184100 i edited my answer check if it works for you and post your markup in your question

Comment: @nicola thanks its working :) .. please don't mind I didn't understand your code can u explain it :)

Comment: @user1184100 i added an explanation

Comment: Be aware that event.target refers directly to the DOM element on which the event has fired, whereas you could also use 'this' inside the event handler, which is jQuery's wrapper for the same DOM element. For avoiding cross-browser issues this is supposed to be better.